# How to view data from MySQL using excel?

Tags: mysql, excel

I am trying to create an excel sheet, where you are able to view MYSQL table without using the **add-in** that MySQL provides. This is because the data can be adjusted, edited or added using this **add-on**.

How can I simply extract MySQL records into an excel for viewing purposes only?

This is what I intend to remove from users touching: [Edit MySQL Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oMLz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to ADO in the VB Editor

Pick the correct connection string for your MySql from [Here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Use something along these lines:

```
Sub Example()
Dim Conn As New Connection
Conn.ConnectionString = "your connection string goes here"
Conn.Open

Dim rs As New Recordset
Dim sql As String
sql = "Select field1,field2 from table"   'put spec of desired table here
rs.Open sql, Conn
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, when I run it says the following error: `Compile Error: User-defined type not defined`

Comment: Have you set the reference to ADO?

Comment: sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: I have used this in connectionstring: `"Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;"`

Comment: In the VB Editor, goto Tools, Options and tick the largest Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects item listed. I can't help on the mysql string - I don't use mysql